# Isomorphic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X_0,X_1\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ are surfaces of degree $d\geq 5$ that are isomorphic as abstract surfaces, why is there an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^3$ that induces an isomorphism between $X_0$ and $X_1$?

(This is Exercise 21.1 (c) in Hartshorne's *Deformation Theory*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L_i=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)|_{X_i}$. If the isomorphism $f:X_0\to X_1$ preserves $L_i$ (that is, $f^*(L_1)=L_0$), rest will easily follow. Now, since $K_{X_i}=L_i^{d-4}$, we have $L_0^{d-4}=f^*L_1^{d-4}$. But (may be one should assume char 0, though may not be necessary), Picard group of hypersurfaces in 3-space is torsion free and since $d>4$, we get $L_0=f^*L_1$. As you can see, the only case which is not covered is when $d=4$.

Comment: What is a good way to see the Picard group of hypersurfaces are torsion free?

Comment: Apriori, I know this only for char 0 and there may be much easier proofs. If $X$ is a degree $d$ hypersurface, let $X_r$ be its order $r$ thickening. Then from the exact sequence, $0\to \mathcal{O}_X(-(r-1)d)\to\mathcal{O}_{X_r}^*\to \mathcal{O}_{X_{r-1}}^*\to 0$, we see that $0\to Pic X_r\to Pic X_{r-1}\to H^2(\mathcal{O}_X(-(r-1)d)$ is exact. Since the last term is a vector space (this is where I need char zero) and the inverse limit of the $Pic$ is just Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^3$, by Grothendieck-Lefscetz, we are done.

Comment: Over complex numbers with $X$ smooth, you could also use the exponential sequence, $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X^*\to 0$ which gives, $Pic\, X\subset H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, and the latter is a finitely generated torsion free abelian group.

Comment: Okay, even if we don't have a proof, it is still true in positive characteristic?

Comment: Why is H^2(X,Z) torsion free in the complex case? I was thinking Lefschetz hyper plane plus universal coefficient theorem, but maybe you had a better idea.

Comment: One of the key results for hypersurfaces in projective $n$-spaces is that they are simply connected if $n\geq 3$. For example, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51301/on-the-fundamental-group-of-hypersurfaces.  From this one can deduce the torsion freeness of $H^2$. One can also see that $Pic$ is torsion free, since a torsion line bundle gives a non-trivial cover, which will say that the surface is not simply connected.